# Multiple weights in survey dataset

Tags: sample-weighting

This is for a simple survey dataset- the client has sample goals on two levels- one for group A vs group B. Another for group X vs group Y. So we have 4 weights affixed to each of these groups. The trouble is a particular respondent could be a part of group A as well as group Y. How can I combine weights for respondents who are a part of multiple groups?